# Espresso: Instrumentation run failed due to 'keyDispatchingTimedOut'

Tags: android, debugging, testing, android-espresso

Below is a section of an espresso test that tries to login to a remote server when a submit button is clicked and then after a successful Login  it checks if the view with test "**FAQ**" is displayed.

```
 onView(withId(R.id.buttonSubmit)).perform(scrollTo());
 onView(withId(R.id.buttonSubmit)).perform(click());
 onView(withText("FAQ")).check(matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
```

The following error is shown when the button is clicked :

[INFO] emulator-52981_unknown_sdk : Run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'keyDispatchingTimedOut'

I would like to know if anybody has an idea of what could be the cause of this error.

Thanks

Comment: did you find answer to this? am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**NOT perform(click()) in UI thread**

below code run in instrument test, throw keyDispatchingTimedOut

```
    try (ActivityScenario<MainActivity> activityScenario
                 = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity.class)) {
        activityScenario.onActivity(activity -> {
            onView(withId(R.id.tv1)).perform(click());
        });
    }
```

change to below code

```
    try (ActivityScenario<MainActivity> activityScenario
                 = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity.class)) {
        onView(withId(R.id.tv1)).perform(click());
    }
```